Mocha test remains running
I'm running mocha tests from node and all of my test cases successfully pass, however, the npm-test command does not terminate once the tests are over. I've simplified my set-up a lot to bring an example here, it still reproduces:
import { expect } from "chai";
import request from "supertest";
import app from '../../../../app.js';
import cases from './demo.case.js';


describe('POST /tournament/create', function () {
    console.log("Demo test started!");
    for (let i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
        const testCase = cases[i];
        if (!testCase.case || !testCase.case.request) {
            console.log(`Skipping: ${testCase.description} as no request is defined!`)
            continue;
        }
        it(testCase.description, async function () {
            try {
                const response = await request(app)
                    .post('/tournament/create')
                    .send(testCase.case.request);
                expect(response.status).to.equal(testCase.case.response.httpCode);
                // Add more assertions as needed
            } catch (error) {
                // Goes to general error handler in app.js
                throw error;
            }
        });
    }
});

This goes through all the cases in demo.case.js file, all end up with their expected result, but the npm-test command does not complete and asks for manual termination with confirmation. Here's the demo.case.js:
const requiredAndOptionalParametersRequest = {
    name: "My tournament",
    registration: {
        registrationStartDateTime: "2100-10-01T12:00:00Z",
        registrationEndDateTime: "2199-10-01T12:00:00Z"
    }
}
const requiredAndOptionalParametersResponse = {
    status: "success",
    httpCode: 200,
    code: "OK",
    message: "Tournament created successfully",
    data: {
        id: "mocked-identifier",
        registrationEnabled: true,
        registrationStartDateTime: "2100-10-01T12:00:00Z",
        registrationEndDateTime: "2199-10-01T12:00:00Z",
        phase: "NOT_STARTED",
        name: "My tournament"
    }
}
const cases = [
    {
        description: "Response matches request input", // Success case
        case: testResponseMatchesInput()
    }
]

function testResponseMatchesInput() {
    return {
        request: requiredAndOptionalParametersRequest,
        response: requiredAndOptionalParametersResponse
    }
}

export default cases;

Any help would be appreciated :)

Figured out the problem. The issue is that i'm using Knex as database connector and it does not automatically destroy the database connections. Thus when npm test is run, the app remains running.
My file structure is in such way that I'm running node server.js which calls app.js. The app.js is also called in test cases as shown above.
Initially the database connection and knex initialization was managed in app.js, but I moved it to server.js and passed it to app.js with dependency injection. By doing this, I also have to define the database for the test case and pass it to app.js, however, defining database in a test case, allows me to call the knex's db.destroy() method in the after block.
